# How to check an id in a webpage is there or not using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me how do we know if an id for any tag in a webpage is present or not. Suggest using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be unclear

For - *How to check an id in a webpage is there or not using jquery*

```
if($("#id_to_search").length) {
        // present
    }
```

and if you want to check if - *how do we know if an id for any tag in a webpage is present or not.*

check if id attribute exist

```
if($(".your_element").attr("id")) {
    // present
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/26nxLze3/4/)

Comment: This checks if an selected element has an given `id`. But it don't check if the element is with that id is available on the page ...

Comment: @eisbehr : i think this is what user wants. check if an id present or not. See  `how do we know if an id for any tag in a webpage is present or not`

Comment: I would read it the other way. And even in the title `how to check an id in a webpage is there or not`. But we will see, maybe you're right. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `length` property of the jQuery object. It is the amount of elements found by the selector. There is no need for use `> 0` too, because `0` is interpreted as `false`.

```
if( $("#myid").length ) {
    // available
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, @SivaManikantaKumarDontamset! Please mark one answer as success then. ;)

Comment: for that my reputation should be changed some more :) anyway +1 for ur ans